# Menu bar doesn't stay in the same position when internet explorer window is maximized?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
html {
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
background-image: url("image/background.jpg");
background-size: 30%;

}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1;
margin: 20px 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

 li {
 float: left;
 }

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-style: bold;

}

li a:hover {
background-color
```

Hello for some reason the menu bar doesn't stay in the same position and then doesn't match the background, its suppose to stay right underneath the where the brown background colour is. Any way to keep it the same position, look at both images attached. thanks.enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2PYn.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kPGo.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Everything hangs on the definition of the brown block, but you are showing neither the html, nor the CSS for it. I can take a wild guess though: does the block have a height of 8%? (If so, the solution lies in the {padding-top}).

Answer (score 0):

Would have to take a look into the HTML markup as well. But from what I have gathered is that the UL that houses the LI items is set to a width of a percentage of the screen and not set to stop at a certain size.